# What is known about $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} x^{n^3} $.

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, special-functions, theta-functions

$f(x) =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}  x^{n^2}$ and similar "theta-type" functions are extensively studied.
They have many properties and occur in number theory , algebra (in particular solving the quintic without hypergeometric functions) , calculus ($q$-analogues) and physics.

But what is known about $g(x) =\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}  x^{n^3}$?

Is that not interesting ? If not, why not ?

I'm confused about this.

Hope this a good question.

For all clarity I'm not asking for demonstrations about $f(x)$ , I know it has many properties.

Too add a more specific question , why doesn't $g(x)$ occur in solving polynomials of degree $>5$?

Comment: Could you please share some context on how $g$ occur when solving equations.

Comment: No AD you got it backwards. Apparantly it does not - as far as i know - and part of the question is if this is true and why ?

Comment: Yes, now I see, I read it too fast.